# Как достать файл по command line bat

Tags: windows, bat

на сервере есть weblogic в нем 2 ноды время от времени нужно их киллять так как память не хватает через bat file написан скрипт который дастает их по `PID` но после каждого перезапуска у них новый `pid` и соответственно скрипт не срабатывает а если сделать по ImageName у них у всех это java в `tasklist`-e как достать их по `command line`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Echo Off
:BEGIN
SET nodeName1=12500

SET RAMLimit=20
Set "sum=0"
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %%a In (
    'TaskList /NH /FI "PID Eq %nodeName1%"') Do Set/A sum+=%%a%%b

if %RAMLimit% LSS %sum% TSKILL 12500 
TIMEOUT /T 600
GOTO BEGIN
```

Comment: *нужно их киллять так как память не хватает* Ну так и проверяй, что ImageName = java и MemUsage > MaxAllowed...

Comment: если я так сделаю он же все процессы java.exe кильнет и у меня консолька тоже кильнется и из за этого у меня нодмэнэджер не запомниться

Comment: *если я так сделаю он же все процессы java.exe кильнет* Это же ж с какого такого перепугу? список ты обрабатываешь построчно. Берёшь очередную строку, вынимаешь токены PID, ImageName и MemUsage, проверяешь по двум последним, и если соответствует, то по первому киляешь вполне себе конкретный процесс... А ещё лучше - сразу зафильтруй по ImageName и MemUsage, чтобы лишнего не молотить: `tasklist /FI "ImageName EQ java.exe" /FI "MemUsage GT 10000000"`

Comment: у всех нодов ImageName это java потому что

Comment: tasklist /FI "ImageName EQ java.exe" /FI "MemUsage GT 10000000" вот этот вариант вроде подходит щас посмотрю че получиться

Comment: *у всех нодов ImageName это java потому что* Да тебе-то какая в пень разница? как я понимаю, только эти два процесса у тебя жрут память как не в себя, остальные-то все скромные, и их килять не нужно.